# If you run SVD on a matrix, how do you transform a new row using the results of that SVD?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, cosine-similarity, svd

I'm using Scipy to run Singular Value Decomposition in order to calculate the cosine similarity between rows in my dataset.  Right now, when I get a new row I'd like to compare, I am re initiliazing the SVD with that new row added.  Is there a way to instead transform the new row using the results (U, S, VT) I got from the initial SVD instead of having to rerun it every time?

```
# calculating similarity for already existing first row
import scipy
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
u, s, v = svds(csr_mat.astype('float'))
similarities = cosine_similarity([u[0]], u)

# when I encounter a new row I want to calculate similarities for, I append it to the original matrix and recalculate SVD
csr_matrix = scipy.sparse.vstack((csr_mat, new_row_to_compare))
u, s, v = svds(csr_mat.astype('float'))
similarities = cosine_similarity([u[-1]], u)
```

Is there some type of linear algebra operation I can do using u, s, and v to transform this `new_row_to_compare`into the same format as the other rows in u?

Comment: You seem to be looking to a rank-one update, and here's a relevant answer on a scicomp SE : https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/updatable-svd-implementation-in-python-c-or-fortran

Answer (score 0):

You want your query to be in the same "space" as the csr_matrix.

1. Make a vector of zeroes that is the same rank (use height b/c "s" is a square) as your "s" matrix. This is called `query_vector` below.
2. For each row of the empty `query_vector` add change the `0` to a `1` where there is a "match"...For example if the rows of your `csr_matrix` represent words in a sentence your `query_vector` would have a `1` wherever a word appears that is also represented in the `csr_matrix`:

   ```
                      sentence1 sentence2 sentence3 query
                cat       0        0          1       0
                dog       1        1          0       1
                mouse     0        1          0       0
                gopher    0        0          1       0
                squirrel  0        0          0       0
   ```
3. Now you can find the cosine distance between the query and the other columns (sentences, in this example).

Sorry I don't have a working example in Python, but there is a GREAT tutorial on how to do this in Python with the gensim package, here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_similarity_queries.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-core-run-similarity-queries-py

Even if you don't use the gensim package I recommend checking out their documentation, it is stellar and I think will answer your question very clearly.

Here is how I do this in R.

```
  # Query Matrix: count the number of times that
  # the word appears - put the counts in the tdm$dimnames$Terms
  # vector.

  query_vector <- rep(0, length(tdm$dimnames$Terms))

  for(i in 1:length(query_split)){
    query_vector[which(tdm$dimnames$Terms == query_split[i])] <- 1
  }

  query_matrix <- as.matrix(query_vector)
  
  # Calculate the cosine similarity between the query and each document.
  full_lsa <- cbind(t(lsa), query_lsa)
  query_scores <- cosine(full_lsa)
```